# How logs will come in production.log ? rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

ruby 2.0 + rails 4.0

When I am starting the server in production mode logs are not coming in the production.log file ? what I need to do configuration.

log file is coming empty

Comment: What about `development.log`?

Comment: in development.log its coming